# Emitting inside express route (using socket.io-client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I recently started refactoring some code to separate front and back end which I previously made into one combined service.

I've now got a problem where I need the web server to emit to the data server (after validation). I previously managed this by calling the emit from inside the express route after adding this code

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.io = io;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.io = socket;
        next();
});

// Then inside of the route

app.post('/make', function(request, response) {
        if (request.session.loggedin = true) {
                var sio = request.io;

                var to = request.body.to;
                var amt = request.body.amt;
                var from = request.body.from;
                if (to.length > 0 && amt != 0) {
                        if (amt <= request.session.balance) {
                          sio.emit('send-transactions', {"to": to, "from": from, "amt": amt});
```

Now that these are separate, the web server is just connecting as client (using socket.io-client) so I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using,

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('wss://ip:port', {secure:true,rejectUnauthorized:false, reconnect:true});
```

I tried changing all references of "io" to "socket" as my vars are different but I can't figure out if it's the client library that isn't capable of doing so .

Tl;dr - I am trying to emit from web server (technically client) to back end (socket.io server) to fire the event which would then broadcast to all clients.

Comment: I see what you are doing, but i dont know how you are doing it. Can you provide socket-io code on the broker (the backend server) and the client code (web server) you are currently using?

Comment: While I was taking a look back through my back end code to give you some context, I noticed that the route "send-transactions" was configured on the clients only and on the server side it's "add" so it was never being fired!

I have gone back and tested and I can see the event being hit on my server side now, while you may not have spent your time writing some dummy code you still helped me solve it haha

Comment: Edit your question or answer yourself, to close this question for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to close this one off so here was the solution:

As my routes were previously intended for server to emit to all clients, using the same route as a client was not being fired on the server side. I just needed to change my route to the server side one and the full sequence is now complete and emitting to that route then gets emitted to all clients